# Share MY_Controller over multiple applications

Tags: codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter's Application Packages feature to load in helpers, config and libraries over multiple applications. See https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html

Now the documentation suggests the following folders can be in the package:

`config/
   helpers/
   language/
   libraries/
   models/`

I also have a controller that I wish to share across multiple applications called MY_Controller, which all applications base controller will inherit from. However, adding in a controller folder does not seem to work. How can I share a controller across multiple applications?

Comment: have you tried putting it in system/core?

Comment: I have not. I was hoping there was a more elegant solution, as when I uprade CI the system folder is replaced so I would prefer to not touch it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this quite simply actually.
Still not as ideal as a proper CI functionality but basically I created the file MY_Controller.php in the /core folder of each application which contains the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * Load the global shared MY_Controller
 */
require_once '/../../shared/core/MY_Controller.php';
```

The beauty of this is I don't need to modify any core files provided by CI including index.php
The only disadvantage is if I have to (ever) rename or move the /shared application I'll have to go and update each MY_Controller with the new path.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably fiddle this using your own `__autoload()` function, [Phil Sturgeon covers a similar thing in this post](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).

For example the following works as expected:

**index.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Look for any non-CI class in the libraries folder
 * @param type $class
 */

function __autoload($class)
{
 if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
 {
  @include_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/'. $class . EXT );
 }
}

[Rest of index.php as normal]
```

**libraries/MY_Controller.php**

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        echo 'my_controller';
    }

}
```

**controllers/nickbarrett.php**

```
<?php

class nickbarrett extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

        echo 'extending my_controller';

    }

    public function index() {

        echo 'index';

    }

}
```

This means you wont have to put anything in the system folder. There's also probably a few places you can put the `__autoload()` function, but index.php seems the simplest.

Note: I've not tried this in an Application Packages scenario so I appreciate if editing every application's index.php may not be feasible for you.

Comment: This is a good solution. Another way would be to create your own loader class MY_Loader and include it in there but you'd have to create this in every application -- more duplication of code. See my answer for the final path I took